# SSH Bash script, can't connect to multiple hosts. Want to use an input file

Tags: bash, for-loop, ssh

I'm trying to connect to multiple hosts to check config files for various things like ldap and dns servers being used. My end goal is to just give it a list of hosts (preferably a file outside of the script), and whatever $SCRIPT I want it to run, and dump it to a file to check for errors. It connects to the first host fine, outputs to file fine, but then just stops, and won't connect to subsequent hosts, namely, app-03.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTS="app-01.stage app-03.stage"
SCRIPT1="hostname"
SCRIPT2="grep ldp-02 /etc/ldap.conf"
SCRIPT3="cat /etc/resolv.conf"
FILE="test.txt"
for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ;
    do 
    ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -n $HOSTNAME "$SCRIPT1; $SCRIPT2; $SCRIPT3"
        if [ "$?" = 1 ]; then
            echo "FAIL - could not connect"
        else
    exit
    fi 
done >> $FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

`exit` does exactly what it sounds like: it exits the script, so your script is done before the second iteration is reached. I think you just want something like

```
for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ;
do 
    ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -n $HOSTNAME "$SCRIPT1; $SCRIPT2; $SCRIPT3"
    if [ "$?" = 1 ]; then
        echo "FAIL - could not connect"        
    fi 
done >> $FILE
```

If `$?` is not 1, you don't need to do anything, and the loop will move on to the next host.

Assuming you are just interested in a non-zero exit code, rather than 1 (as opposed to 2 or 3 or some other code), you can write the `if` statement more idiomatically as

```
if ! ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -n "$HOSTNAME" "$SCRIPT1; $SCRIPT2; $SCRIPT3"; then
    echo "FAIL - could not connect
fi
```